# Multiple line charts in one plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

Here's a sample from the dataframe I have in R:

```
structure(list(Series = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"
), date = structure(c(19415, 19415, 19415, 19415, 19415, 19415,
19415, 19415, 19415, 19415, 19416, 19416, 19416, 19416, 19416,
19416, 19416, 19416, 19416, 19416), class = "Date"), ccy = c("CHF",
"CHF", "EUR", "EUR", "GBP", "GBP", "JPY", "JPY", "USD", "USD",
"CHF", "CHF", "EUR", "EUR", "GBP", "GBP", "JPY", "JPY", "USD",
"USD"), exp = c(-25.0260386883321, -13.4876728854438, 29.9242170197296,
28.1863060040971, -21.1816468152161, -17.6427844100702, -125.811601419233, 
-116.187338952966, -1574.53746806177, -944.410592575117, 13.687475030189,
5.55257290367663, 22.1373554559174, 9.839306286417, 9.60824459042358,
8.43043547492962, 75.9856738242059, 19.8785641759769, -2531.47779912341,
-313.689149325403)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

For each unique value in the column `ccy` I want to create a simple line chart with two series (A and B from column `series`) with values from the columns `date` and `exp`.

Formatting would be the same for each chart, with lines in two different colors and a title that identifies what `ccy` it refers to. The output would be a grid of square line charts.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with ggplot.

```
df = structure(list(Series = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
                          "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"
), date = structure(c(19415, 19415, 19415, 19415, 19415, 19415,
                      19415, 19415, 19415, 19415, 19416, 19416, 19416, 19416, 19416,
                      19416, 19416, 19416, 19416, 19416), class = "Date"), ccy = c("CHF",
                                                                                   "CHF", "EUR", "EUR", "GBP", "GBP", "JPY", "JPY", "USD", "USD",
                                                                                   "CHF", "CHF", "EUR", "EUR", "GBP", "GBP", "JPY", "JPY", "USD",
                                                                                   "USD"), exp = c(-25.0260386883321, -25.0260386883321, 29.9242170197296,
                                                                                                   29.9242170197296, -21.1816468152161, -21.1816468152161, -125.811601419233,
                                                                                                   -125.811601419233, -1574.53746806177, -1574.53746806177, 13.687475030189, 
                                                                                                   13.687475030189, 22.1373554559174, 22.1373554559174, 9.60824459042358,
                                                                                                   9.60824459042358, 75.9856738242059, 75.9856738242059, -2531.47779912341,
                                                                                                   -2531.47779912341)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                                                            -20L))
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |>
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=exp,color=Series)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ccy)
```

[image: Line chart as requested]

Notice that the values you gave for A and B are the same, so the lines are on top of one another.